# Order Select Based on Join Results (Sort Conversations on Last Message Sent)

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, select

I am creating an SQL query in Hibernate for a messaging component. The idea is that I am querying to get *conversations for a user*, **sorted on the date of the last message sent**.

I have two tables: 
 
`conversations` 
[image: Conversations Table]
`messages` 
[image: Messages Table]

In my select query I am attempting something like this but the ordering never happens on the last message sent.

```
String sql =
            "SELECT * FROM conversations " +
            "JOIN messages ON messages.conversation_id = conversations.id "+
            "WHERE (conversations.creator_id = :userId OR conversations.to_id = :userId)" +
            "GROUP BY messages.conversation_id "+
            "ORDER BY messages.created DESC";
```

Comment: @scaisEdge - Not true within MySQL. Also, not applicable since `*` is selecting all columns

Comment: tried the recommended select table.* but still the same results

Comment: @scaisEdge: the statement is categorically incorrect. SQL does allow you to order by expressions that aren't in the SELECT list. (It's possible that some database may have this non-standard restriction, but it's certainly not the case for MySQL or Oracle.)

Comment: Why are you group by conversation_id? Is it so you only get one message back per Conversation?

Comment: @spencer7593 actually this `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2 FROM t ORDER BY c3;` is illegal, and is [explained here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) It should  also be illegal in MySQL's wierdo `group by` but whatever

Comment: The behavior described in the 5.7 docs differs from the behavior of 5.6 and earlier, even with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY included in sql_mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to a MySQL-specific extension to the behavior of the `GROUP BY` clause. Other databases would throw an error... something akin to on-aggregate in SELECT list".  (We can get MySQL to throw a similar error, if we include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode.)

The issue with the expression `messages.created` is that refers to a value from an indeterminate row in the GROUP BY.  The ORDER BY operation occurs much later in the processing, after the GROUP BY operation.

To get the "latest" created for each group, use an *aggregate* expression `MAX(messages.created)`.

To get the other values from that same row, is a little more complicated.

Assuming that `created` is *unique* within a given `conversation_id` group (or, if there's no guaranteed that it's not unique, and you are okay with returning multiple rows with the same value for `created`...

To get the latest `created` for each `conversation_id`

```
SELECT lm.conversation_id
     , MAX(lm.created) AS created
  FROM conversation lc
  JOIN message lm
    ON lm.conversation_id = lc.id
 WHERE (lc.creator_id = :userId OR lc.to_id = :userId)
 GROUP BY lm.conversation_id
```

You can use that as an inline view, to get the whole row with that latest `created`

```
SELECT c.*
     , m.*
  FROM ( SELECT lm.conversation_id
              , MAX(lm.created) AS created
           FROM conversation lc
           JOIN message lm
             ON lm.conversation_id = lc.id
          WHERE (lc.creator_id = :userId OR lc.to_id = :userId)
          GROUP BY lm.conversation_id
       ) l
  JOIN conversation c
    ON c.id = l.conversation_id
  JOIN messages m
    ON m.conversation_id = l.conversation_id
   AND m.created         = l.created
 WHERE (c.creator_id = :userId OR c.to_id = :userId)
```

NOTES:

You can add an `ORDER BY` clause to order the rows returned however you need.

The `WHERE` clause on the outer query is likely redundant, and unnecessary.

We prefer to avoid using `SELECT *`, and prefer to explicitly list the expressions to be returned.

Comment: I upvoted because it's probably what the OP wanted but they may have just wanted `SELECT * FROM (<original statement>) t order by created`

Comment: interesting how the JOIN is on the created date ... will give this a shot. Thanks Spencer... This looks like it is what I need

Comment: @ConradFrix: It's possible that's what OP wants. But usually with questions like this, OP is wanting the "latest" message for each conversation, and is expecting ORDER BY to be applied before the GROUP BY. And that's not the way SQL works.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, this is indeed the correct answer. I have managed to implement it successfully with a couple minor tweaks. Cheers!